# How to expand row in a grid using rowexpander plugin Extjs 4.1.1

Tags: controller, grid, row, extjs4.1

How to expand row in a grid using rowexpander plugin? I am using the following code in my controller

```
'editbasicinfotitlegrid gridview' : {
            afterrender:this.expandAll
 }

expandAll: function(){

    var titlesGrid = Ext.getCmp('editBasicInfoTitleGrid');     
    var expander = titlesGrid.getPlugin('myRowExpander');
    console.log(titlesGrid.plugins[0]);
    expander.toggleRow(0);

}
```

But this code gives me the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'down' of null
```

Comment: alternative to this problem is to fire the expandBody event like this.getCmp().view.fireEvent('expandbody', rowNode, record, nextBd.dom); but i dont know how to get rowNode and the row record

Answer (score 0):

So I have found its solution.The toggleRow() function of RowExpander works only on `viewready` Event of grid.So calling this function on `viewready` instead of `afterrender` worked for me.