# Extjs6: How can I programmactically expand/collapse a row using rowexpander in a grid

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I saw some answers for Extjs4, which use 'toggleRow' method:
[How to expand row in a grid using rowexpander plugin Extjs 4.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340421/how-to-expand-row-in-a-grid-using-rowexpander-plugin-extjs-4-1-1)

but it is no longer available in extjs6. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In fact, it is still available, but they removed it from the docs, I don't know why.](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/source/RowExpander.html#Ext-grid-plugin-RowExpander-method-toggleRow)

Comment: I see. But toggleRow method cannot specify the wanted state. Is there a way to know the current state(expanded/collapsed) of a row?

Comment: @Alex As you may expect, they do exactly that in the function I linked to. If you combine all the different lines they use, you get something like `Ext.fly(plugin.view.getNode(rowIdx)).hasCls(plugin.rowCollapsedCls)`.